# How to make html wait for a function in AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, function, web, wait

I have a object in mainController.js that is set as default as 99.

I am obtaining user location and do running some other function with it to calculate this value.

However, When I load the page, the page seems to load faster than this process. Therefore it displays 99 instead of the calculated value.
If I put console.log after the calculation, the object is successfully changed.

edit1:

```
    status.success( function(data)
{
    $scope.current = data;
    $scope.$broadcast('back_end_connected');
});
$scope.getLocation = function()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position){
            $scope.location = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
            $scope.$broadcast('location_obtained');
            $scope.buildDist();
            $scope.fetch();
            //$scope.getRec();
        });
    }
    else{ 
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
    }
};
var dirBuilt = false;
$scope.$on('location_obtained', function(){
        $scope.buildDist = function()
        {
            if(dirBuilt === false)
                {
                    $scope.facilities[0].distance = distCalc($scope.location.lat,$scope.location.lng,$scope.facilities[0].location.lat,$scope.facilities[0].location.lng);
                    $scope.facilities[1].distance = distCalc($scope.location.lat,$scope.location.lng,$scope.facilities[1].location.lat,$scope.facilities[1].location.lng);
                    $scope.facilities[2].distance = distCalc($scope.location.lat,$scope.location.lng,$scope.facilities[2].location.lat,$scope.facilities[2].location.lng);
                    $scope.facilities[3].distance = distCalc($scope.location.lat,$scope.location.lng,$scope.facilities[3].location.lat,$scope.facilities[3].location.lng);
                    $scope.facilities[4].distance = distCalc($scope.location.lat,$scope.location.lng,$scope.facilities[4].location.lat,$scope.facilities[4].location.lng);
                    $scope.facilities[5].distance = distCalc($scope.location.lat,$scope.location.lng,$scope.facilities[5].location.lat,$scope.facilities[5].location.lng);
                    $scope.$broadcast('dist_obtained');
                    dirBuilt = true;
                    alert("aaa: "+ $scope.facilities[0].distance);
                }
        };
});
```

that "alert("aaa: "+ $scope.facilities[0].distance);" returns the value I want it to display but it is not displayed on the page....
(ng-bind would not work for some reason...)

How can I make the html wait for the operation? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should not make HTML wait until you finish your Js code ! What you should be doing is showing a placeholder value - Loading image so that user know the page is loading some data.

Once you are done with your calculation, hide /replace the loading image with the data you want to show.

**Quick example**

Your view markup will have some HTML element to show the progress bar.And all your other contents will be in another div

```
<body ng-app="yourApp" ng-controller="yourCtrl as vm">
  <div ng-show="loaderCount>0"> Loading something..</div>
  <div ng-show="loaderCount==0">
    <h4>{{userScore}}</h4>
  </div>
</body>
```

And in your angular controller, You have a scope variable called `loaderCount` which you will increase everytime when you are doing some operation (http call/Long running function execution etc..). When you get your result, You decrease this variable value back. In your View You are hiding and showing the Loading Pane based on this value.

```
var yourApp= angular.module('yourApp', []);
var ctrl = function($scope, $http) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.loaderCount = 0;
    vm.someValue = "";
    vm.actionItems = [{ Name: "Test" }, { Name: "Test2" }];

    vm.loaderCount++;

    $http.get("../Home/GetSlowData").then(function(s) {
        vm.loaderCount--;
        vm.someValue = s.data;
    });

};

yourApp.controller('yourCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', ctrl]);
```

*This might not be the best angular code. But this will give you an idea about how to handle this use case.* You should be using services to talk to Http endpoints instead of directly using `$http` in your angular controller.

Note that, `$http.ge`t returns a [**promise**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) which allows you do things when you get the response from this asynchronous operation (the `then` event). You should make sure that your time taking calculation is returning a promise.

Comment: well if I have like
{placeHold: "loading", value: 99}
shows placeHold initially,,,
how do I know when it is doen loading and swap the value?

Comment: `value: 'loading'` and update value with real value after?

Comment: How can I access $scope.loaderCount If I make the http.get call from another file (services) as app.factory??

Comment: @JustinOh Your service method should return a promise and you can update the loadeCount variable in the `then` event of the service method call.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind with the ngBind directive instead of {{}} and not write to the binded property when the calculation is done.
This will hide the result from the view while it is null.

Comment: I've tried that,,, but still does not seem to update after the calculation

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a promise on the service? The function running your calculation can be in a separate angular factory which has .success and .error events to tap into. If the calculation is a success. You can pass the data back to your controller and then bind that data to the controller scope. I'll be at a computer soon and will add some code to explain further if needed.

This would be your distance calculator, I used a Factory over a service but you can read about why to use one over the other

A couple of things to keep in mind. You geolcation is more of a service then something to control since you're requesting from the user, you could add it to the below factory to expand the factories capabilities and allow you to use getLocation in other controllers.

make sure you add the distance service to your html document 
also make sure you put the distance service in your controller and on the main angular app.

**distanceService.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict'
    var distSrvc= angular.module("distanceService",[])
    distSrvc.factory('DistanceCalc',['$http',function($http){

    return{
        getDistance:function(facilitiesData,locationData){

            Object.keys(facilitiesData).length; // or if it's already an array of facilities use facilitiesData.length
           // if its a javascript object and distance is already defined
          for (var distance in facilitiesData) {
             if (facilitiesData.hasOwnProperty(distance)) {
                 facilitiesData.distance  = distCalc(locationData.lat,locationData.lng,facilitieData.location.lat,facilitieData.location.lng);
              }
          }
          // if its an array of objects
          for (var i = 0 ; i< facilitiesData.length;i++){
              facilitiesData[i].distance = distCalc(locationData.lat,locationData.lng,facilitieData.location.lat,facilitieData.location.lng);
          }
        return facilitiesData
    }

})();
```

Then in your controller you'll need to load the service for use.

**yourcontroller.js** this will give errors if you don't load it on the html page and add it to the main angular app.

```
(function(){
        'use strict'
        var myController= angular.module("distanceService",[])
        myController.controller('myController',['$scope','DistanceCalc',function($http,DistanceCalc){ // see how i added the service and passed it to the function
   $scope.getLocation = function(){
    if (navigator.geolocation)
      {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position){
            $scope.location = {lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude};
            $scope.$broadcast('location_obtained');
            $scope.buildDist();
            $scope.fetch();
            //$scope.getRec();
                      });
                  }
                  else{ 
                   alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
            }
        };

        // this line below sends the data to the service
        DistanceCalc.getDistance($scope.facilities,$scope.location)
        .success(function(data){
            //success i'm done running distance calculations and now i want to update the facilties object with the added distance

            $scope.facilities = data
        })
        .error(function(data){
        // some error occurred and data can tell you about that error
        })
    }
})();
```

Comment: I've uploaded some of my code that I thought it was relevant....
Plez help when u got time :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like this:

```
$scope.value = "Loading";
or
$scope.value = "";
$scope.calculate = function() {
    $scope.value = yourcalculation;
}
$scope.calculate();
```

Or in your case i think if you use $scope.$apply() after you add data to your scope element will do the trick

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$scope.$on('location_obtained', function(){
        $scope.buildDist = function()
        {
            if(dirBuilt === false)
                {
                    $scope.facilities[0].distance = distCalc($scope.location.lat,$scope.location.lng,$scope.facilities[0].location.lat,$scope.facilities[0].location.lng);
                    $scope.facilities[1].distance = distCalc($scope.location.lat,$scope.location.lng,$scope.facilities[1].location.lat,$scope.facilities[1].location.lng);
                    $scope.facilities[2].distance = distCalc($scope.location.lat,$scope.location.lng,$scope.facilities[2].location.lat,$scope.facilities[2].location.lng);
                    $scope.facilities[3].distance = distCalc($scope.location.lat,$scope.location.lng,$scope.facilities[3].location.lat,$scope.facilities[3].location.lng);
                    $scope.facilities[4].distance = distCalc($scope.location.lat,$scope.location.lng,$scope.facilities[4].location.lat,$scope.facilities[4].location.lng);
                    $scope.facilities[5].distance = distCalc($scope.location.lat,$scope.location.lng,$scope.facilities[5].location.lat,$scope.facilities[5].location.lng);
                    $scope.$broadcast('dist_obtained');
                    dirBuilt = true;
                    alert("aaa: "+ $scope.facilities[0].distance);
                    $scope.$apply(); // This should do the trick
                }
        };
});
```